# 'Winmm.lib' error in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012

I am working on a project on Opengl in C++ in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8.
It compiled successfully but when i deploy it,... It gives the error of 'winmm.lib' file...

error LNK1104: cannot open file 'winmm.lib'.

How to download winmm.lib file and from where?

Answer (score 2):

It's part of the Windows SDK. Which... you need to develop Windows applications. :)

Comment: Graphics in opengl using c++

Comment: @MuhammadZia Huh? What about "graphics in opengl using c++"?

Comment: My teacher asked me to make a menu bar in opengl with c++. I am working on it and when i deploy my project it produces an error...     Error 1 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'winmm.lib'

Comment: Just inform me about 'winmm.lib'. If anyone has knowledge of it

Comment: I did. Did you read my answer? If you don't *understand* my answer, or if you need additional information, just say so. But I did inform you about winmm.lib. It is part of the Windows SDK, so if you have the Windows SDK, you also have winmm.lib. And if you don't have winmm.lib, then it is because you haven't installed the Windows SDK.